# Arduino -> Processing conversion: creating mux channels

Tags: c, array, processing-lang, multiplexer

As the title alludes to, I'm in the process of converting an Arduino sketch to a Processing sketch. So far, mostly pretty straightforward.

I'm running into an issue with creating an array of ints for the channels for two [muxers](http://bildr.org/2011/02/cd74hc4067-arduino/). Below is the code that I currently have working for the Arduino sketch:

```
int writeMux(int channel){
  int controlPin[] = {s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7};

  int muxChannel[20][8]={
    //Mux 1 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 0
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 1
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 2
    {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 3
    {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 4
    {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 5
    {0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 6
    {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 7
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0}, //channel 8
    {1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0}, //channel 9

    //Max 2
    {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0}, //channel 0
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0}, //channel 1
    {1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0}, //channel 2
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0}, //channel 3
    {1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0}, //channel 4
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0}, //channel 5
    {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0}, //channel 6
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0}, //channel 7
    {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1}, //channel 8
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1}, //channel 9
  }; 

  //loop through the 4 sig
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++){
    digitalWrite(controlPin[i], muxChannel[channel][i]);
  }

  //write the value at the SIG pin
  analogWrite(SIG_pin, testValue);  

  //return the value
  return 0;
}
```

Below is the slightly varied version that I'm using for my Processing-equivelent sketch.

```
int readMux(int channel){
  int controlPin[] = {s0, s1, s2, s3};

  int muxChannel[20][8]={
    //Mux 1 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 0
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 1
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 2
    {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 3
    {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 4
    {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 5
    {0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 6
    {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}, //channel 7
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0}, //channel 8
    {1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0}, //channel 9

    //Max 2
    {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0}, //channel 0
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0}, //channel 1
    {1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0}, //channel 2
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0}, //channel 3
    {1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0}, //channel 4
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0}, //channel 5
    {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0}, //channel 6
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0}, //channel 7
    {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1}, //channel 8
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1}, //channel 9
  }; 


  //loop through the 4 sig
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
    digitalWrite(controlPin[i], muxChannel[channel][i]);
  }

  //write the value at the SIG pin
  arduino.analogWrite(SIG_pin, testValue);  

  int val = 0;
  return val;
}
```

I'm currently getting an error of `unexpected token: int` error at the following line:

```
  int muxChannel[20][8]={
```

And, an error of `The type of expression must be an array type but it resolved to int` at this line:

```
digitalWrite(controlPin[i], muxChannel[channel][i]);
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to be a Java expert, your code is C.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html